# SoapUI with Fiddler

Tags: fiddler, soapui

I am trying to route my soapUI web service requests via fiddler, but it doesn't seems to work. I tried url's like

```
http://localhost./myservice/myservice.asmx
http://localhost:8888/myservice/myservice.asmx
```

The later one though goes via fiddler, but it returns the request itself rather than the response from webservice. Any help?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try File > Preferences > Proxy Settings
Host 127.0.0.1
Port 8888

and use http://localhost/myservice/myservice.asmx

[Here is a post that explain this a little bit more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249303/Testing-and-Monitoring-WCF-Service-using-soapUI-an)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I just had to set the proxy settings after adding the wsdl to soapUI project.

Answer (score 10):

To decrypt HTTPS traffic generated by SoapUI, you may need to import Fiddler certificate into the Java truststore file, *cacerts*. For SoapUI this file is typically located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\jre\lib\security\" (or whatever version and path you installed it at).

1. In Fiddler, export the root certificate to your desktop: **Tools > Fiddler Options... > HTTPS > Export Root Certificate to Desktop**.
2. Run `cmd` as administrator.
3. `cd` to the *security* folder of SoapUI's JRE, e.g.:

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.0.0\jre\lib\security\"
   ```
4. Back up the *cacerts* file:

   ```
    xcopy cacerts cacerts.bak
   ```
5. Import Fiddler certificate:

   ```
    ..\..\bin\keytool.exe -import -alias fiddler -file "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\FiddlerRoot.cer" -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
   ```

   Here "changeit" is the password to the *cacerts* store.
6. When prompted to trust the certificate, enter `yes`.
7. Restart SoapUI.

8. Configure SoapUI to use Fiddler as proxy: go to **File > Preferences > Proxy Settings** and specify:

   - Proxy Setting: Manual
   - Host: localhost
   - Port: 8888 (or whatever port your Fiddler uses)

Remember to restore the original proxy settings when Fiddler is not running.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler injects itself automatically as a proxy, but only into the IE stack.  SoapUI uses a java stack, so the proxy isn't automatic.

Comment: So my question would be how do i attach fiddler to soapUI?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it happens that default port **8888** is used by some other application. Like in my case it was **python** so it did not worked using 8888

So the port number you mention should be the one where Fiddler is listening.

capture snapshots so its easy to understand

```
Step 1 & Step 2 to be performed on Fiddler
Step 3 & Step 4 on Soapui/ReadyaPI
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
http://localhost/myservice/myservice.asmx (without the dot)
```

UPDATE

Fiddler works by acting as a proxy on your machine. When started it will set itself up on port 8888. That's why you're seeing it work when you use `localhost:8888`. If you want to use `localhost` then you'll need to tell fiddler to look at port 80.

From the Internet Explorer main menu, click **Tools**, click **Internet Options**, click **Connections**, click **LAN Setting**, and finally click **Advanced**. Now change the port to 80 and see if that works.

Comment: All other requests that are fired from browser are going via fiddler. But the requests that are made from soapUI are not getting routed through fiddler. Do you think we need to make any changes to soapUI options?

Comment: What's the url you're using with SoapUI? Is it `localhost`?

Comment: I tried the below three

http://localhost/myservice/myservice.asmx
http://localhost./myservice/myservice.asmx
http://localhost:8888/myservice/myservice.asmx